# Meteor - Generate and Download file in the client side

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Is there any way to generate a csv file and download it in the client side using meteor? I would the user to be able to click a button and then a file would be downloaded without leaving the current page.

```
Template.analytics.events({
  'click .csv-export' (event, template) {  
      const json2csv = require('json2csv');
      let fields = ['timestamp', 'user', 'category', 'action'];
      let data = Analytics.find({}).fetch();
      try {
        let result = json2csv({data: data, fields: fields});
        var filename = 'test.csv';
        var headers = {
         'Content-Type': 'text/csv',
         'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename=" + filename
        };
        this.response.writeHead(200, headers);
        this.response.end(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes it is possible, do you have some code already to show? Otherwise this is very general and solution-demanding. Have you included any npm package for csv export?

Comment: hey @Jankapunkt I added some code which isn't working but has you can have an idea on what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: Ah I see!  Does this help you? See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/qm5AG/
Edit: replace the part with this.response with some of the code in the fiddle. Should work.

Comment: @Jankapunkt wow great. that does it. thanks!!

Comment: Please post your working code as answer, so that others can benefit from it, too. ;-)

Comment: @Jankapunkt done

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jankapunkt I was able to solve this. 
Here's the answer, all the code is inside Template.onRendered.

```
// DOWNLOAD CSV

  this.csvFile = null,
    makeTextFile = function() {
      var csv = json2csv(Analytics.find({}).fetch(), true, false);

      var data = new Blob([csv], {
        type: 'text/csv'
      });

      if (this.csvFile !== null) {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.csvFile);
      }

      this.csvFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);

      return this.csvFile;
    };

  let csvExport = document.getElementById('csv-export');

  csvExport.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let downloadLink = makeTextFile();
    window.open(downloadLink, '_blank');
  }, false);

  //END DOWNLOAD CSV
```